# TXT to CSV with data in different columns

Tags: unix

I need to convert in UNIX a txt file to csv format having all data in different columns.
TXT file look like :

```
19-OCT-13        0        1        0        0    
20-OCT-13       12       21        0        6
```

and would need a csv file with same data but in different columns instead that all line entry in a single column.

I've tried with several commands like sede, pr , cut with related options but can not get the required result .
Not good for me to make a loop therefore a command line would be the best solution.
Can you please please help here ? 
Thanks
/Gia.

Comment: please edit your question to include "the desired result". Use the `{}` code fmt tool at the top left of the edit box to get correct formatting on selected text. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "20-OCT-13 12 21 0 6" | sed 's#-# #g'
```

Using Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR="20-OCT-13 12 21 0 6"
echo $VAR | sed 's#-# #g'
```

You can easily embed this code inside a bash for loop.